# How can a methyl halide react by intramolecular SN2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, erratum, nucleophilic-substitution

> Out of the following, $\ce{CH3Br}$ doesn't react by which mechanism?
>
> 1. S<sub>N</sub>2
> 2. S<sub>N</sub>1
> 3. E2
> 4. Intramolecular S<sub>N</sub>2
> 5. E1

My textbook gives 2, 3 and 5 as the correct answers, which means it does react by 1 and 4.

But how can a methyl halide react by intramolecular S<sub>N</sub>2, without a nucleophile present in the molecule? There's just a leaving group ($\ce{-Br}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. There is no way that a one-carbon and one-heteroatom compound could react by intramolecular substitution. All intramolecular nucleophilic substitutions will require some ring-like transition state. The smallest ring you can build is a three-membered ring — but bromomethane does not have three atoms that could build up that ring (hydrogen does not participate).